# VSCode: how to restore "Go To File" seaarch bar and keep it on screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code

> Note: after Googling I discovered that this feature is called "Quick Open" and it's not a settable feature, it's part of "command center"

Today, after updating vscode, I lost a feature I love.

I had the search bar of the "Go To File..." feature always available on screen

Since today, I haven't it on screen anymore. I can activate, on Windows, using classic Ctrl+P, but I cannot find the setting to restore and keep the file search bar visible on screen

It was between windows title and the tabs titles

Comment: Oh, yes ! I voted to close my own question.

I was UNABLE TO FIND this because i was not aware of original name of the feature. Please do not downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable windows command center

If not visible, right-click on left or right icon and enable Quick Open from popup menu